# The last step of proof of Converse mapping for Mellin Transform

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-integration, mellin-transform

[image]

[image]

No matter how I tried to understand the red box,

I still get $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}(1+t)^{r/2}}dt$ , and this is a dead end to me.

Can anyone explain it?